# How to speed up MongoDB data type change in a large collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

We have a lot of strings stored where there should be Decimals.  I'm trying to convert them using this.  But its really slow.  I feel like just getting a list of all the records to change and doing one giant update might be way faster?  Am I doing something wrong that this is so slow?

```
{ obj.CASH_REPORTED = new NumberDecimal(obj.CASH_REPORTED); db.HOLDINGS.save(obj); });
```

We do have 18 million records, most of which are type:string.

The query is actually not showing above and is:

```
db.HOLDINGS.find({CASH_REPORTED: {$type: "string"}}
).noCursorTimeout().forEach(function(obj) { 
    obj.CASH_REPORTED = new NumberDecimal(obj.CASH_REPORTED); 
    db.HOLDINGS.save(obj); 
});
```

Comment: the query is actually not showing above and is:      db.HOLDINGS.find({CASH_REPORTED: {$type: "string"}}).noCursorTimeout().forEach(function(obj) { obj.CASH_REPORTED = new NumberDecimal(obj.CASH_REPORTED); db.HOLDINGS.save(obj); });

Comment: Take a look at $convert https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you working with? MongoDB version 4.2 allows using an Aggregation Pipeline in an update operation- this is more efficient than the way you are performing the update: [Update with Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html#update-many-update).